# Query in MongoDB with MutliCollection Aggregation, Joins

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema

I want to make a Query on MongoDb like **Select * from Person, School WHERE Person.pID == School.pID**. How Can I do this on MongoDB. With Scrapy I had scrapped this [page](http://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/OCTOPUS;jsessionid=90C13DB66DC23B58410C25CA5724EAC0) and had already the Collection, and I want to make the Foreign Key Relation between the Collection with Mongoose. How Can I do this on this given Example?. Thanks.
(First Collection is School Second Collection is Person)

```
/* School Collection */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("574453fb085516029132205a"),
    "involvedInst" : [ 
        "10403"
    ],
    "instID" : [ 
        "10359"
    ],
    "projID" : [ 
        "271289"
    ],
    "fSpeaker" : [],
    "pID" : [ 
        "1229134"
    ],
    "speaker" : [ 
        "Professor Dr. Georg  Reiser"
    ]
}

/* PersonCollection */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("574453fb085516029132205a"),
    "beteiligteInstituten" : [ 
        "10403"
    ],
    "instID" : [ 
        "10359"
    ],
    "projID" : [ 
        "271289"
    ],
    "fachlicherDFGAnsprechpartner" : [],
    "pID" : [ 
        "1229134"
    ],
    "speaker" : [ 
        "Professor Dr. Georg  Reiser"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since version 3.2 MongoDB has $lookup option for aggregations (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). If your MongoDB version is less than 3.2 you need to produce two queries and make join in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In version 3.2 there is a new feature to lookup another collection in the aggregate function.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

In your case you can use $lookup like:

```
db.person.aggregate([
    {$lookup:
       {
          from: "school",
          localField: "pId",
          foreignField: "pId",
          as: "person_school"
       } 
    }
])
```

The document will return as

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5745805a39c36b72fb8e34a9"),
    "beteiligteInstituten" : [
            "10403"
    ],
    "instID" : [
            "10359"
    ],
    "projID" : [
            "271289"
    ],
    "fachlicherDFGAnsprechpartner" : [ ],
    "pID" : [
            "1229134"
    ],
    "speaker" : [
            "Professor Dr. Georg  Reiser"
    ],
    "person_school" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5745802a39c36b72fb8e34a8"),
                    "involvedInst" : [
                            "10403"
                    ],
                    "instID" : [
                            "10359"
                    ],
                    "projID" : [
                            "271289"
                    ],
                    "fSpeaker" : [ ],
                    "pID" : [
                            "1229134"
                    ],
                    "speaker" : [
                            "Professor Dr. Georg  Reiser"
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

It is possible to use multiple lookups across collections.

```
db.person.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
            {
            from: "school",
            localField: "pId",
            foreignField: "pId",
            as: "person_school"
        }
   },
   {
        $lookup:
            {
            from: "teacher",
            localField: "pId",
            foreignField: "pId",
            as: "person_teacher"
        }
   }
])
```

But you should consider using embedded documents or document references.
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: @Nodari Thanks . How Can I make joins from three Collections?

Comment: Use could use multiple $lookup in the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: How Can I Use embedded Documents, When I have already scrapped it with scrapy or referenced it with dbrefs. How should dbref must seem, when in the given example pID is the **foreign key and primary Key**